# Electric fields and a conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I'll quote the lines from my textbook-

> "Consider a charged conductor with a small area element ds. Assume we have two points A and B just at the surface and well inside the conductor, respectively. Also assume that $E$ is the electric field due to the charge on $ds$, and $E'$ is the field due to the remaining part of the conductor. If we assume $E(a)$ to be the net electric field at A, then $E(a)= E + E'$."

And I'm okay with this so far. But then it says, " At A we have $E + E' = \frac{X}{\epsilon_0}$ (X is the surface charge density, $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space) and at B we have $E + E' =0$".
And further, they have added the equations and found the values of $E$ and $E'$.
And this doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the values of $E$ and $E'$ vary with space, especially when we're talking about a randomly shaped conductor?

Comment: Electric field just above the surface is $\sigma / \epsilon_0$ by Gauss's law. Inside the conductor, electric field is always zero in electrostatics.

Comment: What book is this from? Reminds me of irodov

Answer (score 0):

If there was an electric field inside a (non-powered) conductor, the free electrons would be pushed around until there was no field. Hence E (from outside) + E' (from inside) = 0 at every point inside. (Both E's will vary from point to point, but might be evaluated at a chosen point.)

Comment: I have understood what you wrote in the end, but I think you didn't understand my question. If E and E' do vary, then we cannot consider them to be the very same variables in both the equations! Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The two equations in your discussion describe the field at two different points: one just outside the conductor and another inside.